# Get variable from other file's class function

Tags: php, variables, var

I want to get variable from other file's class function.
Something like this :

```
file lang.php:
<?php
  class lang
  {
    function get()
  {
  $dubs = "dubs";
?>

file print.php:
<?php
  require("lang.php");
  lang::get();
  echo $dubs;
?>
```

But this returns nothing...

Comment: Are you sure you grasp the concepts of object-oriented programming?

Comment: Return the value form `get` and assign it to a variable. You should read about scope in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. You'd also have to create an instance of the class before you can call `get`. I suggest to read http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: I have a lot of varables in that get(); function.

Comment: And you want to be able to access all of them in the caller? Then you have a fundamental design issue... stop coding and think about the overall problem again.

Answer (score 1):

The variable $dubs can only be used inside the function get(), because you declared it there. If you want to use it outside, there are two options: or return its value in the function (add return $dubs at the end), and the do something like $a = lang->get();, or make it global, declaring it outside any function in the class. Which method to use depends on the propouse of the class and the function; if you are going to use the value in other functions of this class, then make it global.

Comment: I don't want to declare it outside the function.

Comment: Then `return $dubs;` in your function, and say `$dubs = lang::get();` in your main code.

Comment: I have a lot of variables in that function.

Comment: If you want at them, then either declare them global or return an array containing the ones you want.  Other than that, you're screwed -- local scope means the vast majority of those variables *don't even exist* once the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way would be

```
$lang = new lang();
$dubs = $lang->get();
echo $dbus;
```

Comment: Does `lang::get()` return anything?

Comment: No. I just want to get it's $dubs.

Comment: What if it doesn't want you touching its $dubs?  Hmm?

Comment: What? Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.

Comment: You clearly need clarification on the ideas of scope and visibility.  `$dubs` only exists and is visible within `lang::get`.  If `lang::get` wanted you to see `$dubs`, it would declare the variable as global or pass it somewhere or return it.  That's just how things work.  The absence of any of those means you don't get to see `$dubs`.  Period.

Answer (score 0):

$dubs will only be visible within the function it was created. You are also calling the method as if it was a static one. You need to use the regular syntax:

```
class lang
{
    function get()
    {
        $dubs = "dubs";
        return $dubs;
    }
}

$lang = new lang()
echo $lang->get();
```

Comment: In this case, static vs not doesn't matter much.  For backward-compatibility reasons (PHP4 did the bare minimum to support classes), static functions don't have to be labeled as such.

Comment: Just noticed some more - updated my comment to reflect the scope of $dubs.

Comment: I have a lot of variables in that function.

Comment: If you create a variable (in this case $dubs) inside a method - it'll only ever be visible to code inside that method. You need to instead perhaps pass an argument to the method, and then echo out based on the argument. What you CAN'T do though, is call $dubs from anywhere other than inside get().

Answer (score 0):

As Luan Nico [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9363391/1220835):

```
class lang
{
    function get()
    {
         return "dubs";
    }
}
$lang = new lang();
$dubs = $lang->get();
```

OR

```
class lang
{
    static function get()
    {
        return "dubs";
    }
}

$dubs = lang::get();
```

OR

```
class lang
{
    static function get(&$dubs)
    {
        $dubs = "dubs";
    }
}

lang::get($dubs);
```

OR

```
class lang
{
    static $dubs = "dubs";
}

$dubs = lang::$dubs;
```

Comment: Never mind just did in more crappy way.