# Reading SOAP XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I do a SOAP-call to my client. It returns a XML-document as a string (this is a workaround that I can't do anything about). I have the XML in a variable and I need to read this XML to grab the information I want.

I am looking for the fields `DomesticCustomer`, `Addresses` and `GridOwner`. I guess if someone helps me to get to the `DomesticCustomer`-part I can do the rest on my own.

Note: In this example, there is only one entry under each field, but there could be multiple, so I need to be able to foreach this.

**Note #2: Because the client I use has some weird workaround for this to work, the response (the xml) is a simple string.**

The XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <MeteringPointIdResponse xmlns="http://www.ediel.no/schemas/public/nubix/MeteringPointIdResponse">
            <RequestId xmlns="">3423424234</RequestId>
            <Requestor xmlns="">
                <GLN>234234234</GLN>
            </Requestor>
            <Customers xmlns="">
                <DomesticCustomer>
                    <LastName>Name</LastName>
                    <FirstName>Name</FirstName>
                    <BirthDate>xxx-xx-xx</BirthDate>
                    <MeterNumber>xxxxx</MeterNumber>
                    <Addresses>
                        <Address>
                            <Address1>345345</Address1>
                            <PostCode>3514</PostCode>
                            <Location>xxxxxx</Location>
                            <CountryCode>xx</CountryCode>
                            <Installation>
                                <Description>xxxxx</Description>
                                <MeteringPointId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</MeteringPointId>
                                <MeteringMethod>xxxxxx</MeteringMethod>
                                <InstallationStatus>xxxx</InstallationStatus>
                                <LastReadOffDate>xxxx-xx-xx</LastReadOffDate>
                            </Installation>
                            <GridOwner>
                                <GLN>xxxxxxx</GLN>
                                <Name>xxxxxxxx</Name>
                                <ProdatAddress>
                                    <InterchangeRecipient>
                                        <Id>xxxxxxx</Id>
                                        <Qualifier>xx</Qualifier>
                                        <Subaddress>xxxxx</Subaddress>
                                    </InterchangeRecipient>
                                    <Party>
                                        <Id>xxxxxxxxxx</Id>
                                        <CodeListResponsible>xxxx</CodeListResponsible>
                                    </Party>
                                    <EDISyntax>
                                        <CharSet>xxx</CharSet>
                                        <SyntaxId>xxxx</SyntaxId>
                                    </EDISyntax>
                                    <SMTPAddress>test@hey.com</SMTPAddress>
                                </ProdatAddress>
                            </GridOwner>
                        </Address>
                    </Addresses>
                </DomesticCustomer>
            </Customers>
        </MeteringPointIdResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get variable from other file's class function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363308/get-variable-from-other-files-class-function)

Comment: Did you even read my question? This is about reading an XML-document that I have in a variable. As far away from related as possible.

Comment: And how is that not a duplicate then? Load the variable with SimpleXML, then you can access it like shown. Besides how to parse and process XML, SOAP or HTML has been answered way too often to have yet another question asking how to get `<randomElement/>` from an XML document. There is nothing specific in your question to justify not closing it. Just look at the Related Section to the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the built in library for php, it parses the response and returns a mixed object/array object that is INFINITELY easier to deal with than the xml

Edit: since you are using php's built in client, here is a simple class that I wrote built around it. It "flattens" the responce and makes it easy to retrieve responces like:

```
$soap = new SOAP($wsdl, $options);
$soap->call("stuff goes here");
$soap->find("what you are looking for goes here");

    /**
     * @author Troy Knapp
     * @copyright 2011
     * 
     * @version .1.1
     */

class Soap {

    //***VARIABLES***//
var $request; //..............string; holds last soap request
var $requestHeaders; //.......string; holds the headers for the last request
var $response; //.............string; xml response
var $responseHeaders; //......string; holds the headers for the last response
var $result; //...............array; the soap response parsed into an array
var $wsdlLocation; //.........string; url for the wsdl
var $parameters; //...........array; saved array of parameters
var $function; //.............string; name of function to be accessed
var $findResult = array();
var $flatArray = array(); //..array; holds an easy to search array
//
//***OBJECTS***//
var $client; //...................instance of SoapClient
var $exception; //................obj; SoapFault exception object
//    
//***DEFAULTS***//
public $options = array(
    'trace' => 1
);

function __construct($wsdl, $options = false) {
    if ($options == false) {
        $options = $this->options;
    } else {
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    $this->wsdlLocation = $wsdl;

    $this->client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
}

/*
 * Executes a given function when supplied the proper function name, 
 * parameters and options.
 */
function call($function, $parameters, $options=NULL) {
    $this->function = $function;
    $this->parameters = $parameters;

    try {
        //$this->response = $this->client->__soapCall($function, $parameters, $options);
        $this->response = $this->client->$function($parameters, $options);
    } catch (SoapFault $exception) {
        $this->$exception = $exception;
    }

    //get info about the last request
    $this->request = $this->client->__getLastRequest();
    $this->requestHeaders = $this->client->__getLastRequestHeaders();

    //more info about the last responce
    $this->responseHeaders = $this->client->__getLastResponseHeaders();

    //set up an easily searchable array of results
    $this->flatten();

    return $this->response;
}

/*
 * Prints all kinds of interesting info about what went on for debugging 
 * purposes
 */
function printInfo() {
    echo '<h2>SoapClient Info:</h2>';
    echo 'wsdl location: ' . $this->wsdl_location . '<br/>';
    echo 'SoapClient Options:';
    echoPre($this->options);

    echo '<h2>Call Info:</h2>';
    echo 'Function Name: ' . $this->function . '<br/>';
    echo 'Parameters: ';
    echoPre($this->parameters);


    echo '<h2>Last Request: <br></h2>';
    echo $this->format($this->request);

    echo '<h2>Request Headers: <br></h2>';
    echo $this->format($this->requestHeaders);

    echo '<h2>Last Response: <br></h2>';
    echoPre($this->response);

    echo '<h2>Response Headers: <br></h2>';
    echo $this->format($this->responseHeaders);
}

/*
 * Formats the xml to make it nice and purdy for display and debugging
 * purposes
 */
function format($xml) {

    // add marker linefeeds to aid the pretty-tokeniser (adds a linefeed between all tag-end boundaries)
    $xml = preg_replace('/(>)(<)(\/*)/', "$1\n$2$3", $xml);

    // now indent the tags
    $token = strtok($xml, "\n");
    $result = ''; // holds formatted version as it is built
    $pad = 0; // initial indent
    $matches = array(); // returns from preg_matches()
    // scan each line and adjust indent based on opening/closing tags
    while ($token !== false) :

        // test for the various tag states
        // 1. open and closing tags on same line - no change
        if (preg_match('/.+<\/\w[^>]*>$/', $token, $matches)) :
            $indent = 0;
        // 2. closing tag - outdent now
        elseif (preg_match('/^<\/\w/', $token, $matches)) :
            $pad--;
        // 3. opening tag - don't pad this one, only subsequent tags
        elseif (preg_match('/^<\w[^>]*[^\/]>.*$/', $token, $matches)) :
            $indent = 1;
        // 4. no indentation needed
        else :
            $indent = 0;
        endif;

        // pad the line with the required number of leading spaces
        $line = str_pad($token, strlen($token) + $pad, ' ', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $result .= $line . "\n"; // add to the cumulative result, with linefeed
        $token = strtok("\n"); // get the next token
        $pad += $indent; // update the pad size for subsequent lines    
    endwhile;

    $result = highlight_string($result);

    //nl2br(htmlentities($result));
    return $result;
}

/*
 * Searches the pre flattened array for a given key. If there is only one
 * result, this will return a single value, if there are multiple results,
 * it will return an array of values.
 * 
 * @param string; $search - search for a response with this key
 */
function find($search=false) {
    if ($search == false) {
        return $this->flatArray;
    } else {
        if (isset($this->flatArray[$search])) {
            $result = $this->flatArray[$search];
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(count($result)==1){
        return $result[0];
    }
    else{
        return $result;
    }
}

/*
 * This method flattens an array/object result into an array that is easy 
 * to search through. Search terms are set as keys with results set as 
 * arrays owned by said keys.
 */

function flatten($array=false) {
    if ($array == false) {
        $array = $this->response;
    }
    if (is_object($array)) {
        //get the variables of object
        $array = get_object_vars($array);
    }

    //howdy('array');
    //echoPre($array);
    //echo "_______________<br>";

    if (is_array($array)) {

        //loop through the sub elements and make sure they are arrays
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            //if it's an object, we need to convert it to an array
            if (is_object($value)) {
                //get the variables of object
                $value = get_object_vars($value);
            }

            //echo "key: $key value: ";
            //echoPre($value);
            //echo "_______________<br>";

            //push the key=>value pairs to the flat array
            if (!isset($this->flatArray[$key])) {
                $this->flatArray[$key] = array();
            }

            array_push($this->flatArray[$key], $value);

            if (is_array($value)) {
                $this->flatten($value);
            }
        }
    }
}

function getWSDL() {
    $wsdl = file_get_contents($this->wsdlLocation);
}
```

}

Comment: Because this is a workaround for our provider, the XML is just a simple string when it's returned. I need to get the xpath for this loop to work.

Comment: I've gone down the rabbit hole of trying to convert XML to an array, then iterate over that array to try and parse values from it... unless you are much smarter than I am, I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: See my own answer belove. It was not that difficult.

Answer (score 1):

It was that simple. Forgot to register the namespace.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
foreach ($xml->xpath('//DomesticCustomer') as $item)
{
    print_r($item);
}
```

Comment: you are not using the namespace in the XPath query, so this has nothing to do with registering the namespace. Proof: http://codepad.viper-7.com/KuvI4C

Answer (score -2):

Use http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php (Proving your on PHP5)

Comment: I am...that is not an answer to this question at all.

Comment: Sorry, I read it too quickly and assumed the wrong thing, my bad :)